# How to test a web page using selenium through a desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, testing, selenium, desktop

I need to test a webpage via desktop application, I'm trying to use
the selenium IDE, I had sucess to create the test cases, but I'm not
able to execute them on java.

I've been looking for something helpful, but I can't find any help at all.

Thank you

Comment: Desktop application are you talking about a browser like IE , Firefox or chrome ???

Comment: The IDE allows you to export it as Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A framework that has been created for just this cause, (it's in Java) can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip) or you can check the project out from github [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium).

This project was designed to be very simple, yet very effective.  This type of framework is a "free version" of my interpretation of a framework that I use every day in production-type environments.

There is a sample test that is enclosed in the project named `SampleFunctionalTest.java`. Assuming you follow the ReadMe to the T, you should have no problem getting started.

Here is what a test would look like in this framework.

```
@Config(url = "http://ddavison.github.io/tests/getting-started-with-selenium.htm", browser = Browser.FIREFOX) // You are able to specify a "base url" for your test, from which you will test. You may leave `browser` blank.
public class SampleFunctionalTest extends AutomationTest {

    /**
     * You are able to fire this test right up and see it in action.  Right click the test() method, and click "Run As... jUnit test".
     * 
     * The purpose of this is to show you how you can continue testing, just by taking the semi colon out, and continuing with your test.
     */
    @Test
    public void test() {

            // click / validateAttribute
        click(props.get("click"))
        .validateAttribute(props.get("click"), "class", "success") // validate that the class indeed added.

        // setText / validateText
        .setText(By.id("setTextField"), "woot!")
        .validateText(By.id("setTextField"), "woot!") // validates that it indeed set.

        // check / uncheck
        .check(By.id("checkbox"))
        .validateChecked(By.id("checkbox")) // validate that it checked

        .check(props.get("radio.2")) // remember that props come from <class name>.properties, and are always CSS selectors. (why use anything else, honestly.)
        .validateUnchecked(props.get("radio.1")) // since radio 1 was selected by default, check the second one, then validate that the first radio is no longer checked.

        // select from dropdowns.
        .selectOptionByText(By.xpath("//select[@id='select']"), "Second") // just as a proof of concept that you can select on anything. But don't use xpath!!
        .validateText(By.id("select"), "2") // validateText() will actually return the value="" attr of a dropdown, so that's why 2 works but "Second" will not.

        .selectOptionByValue(By.cssSelector("select#select"), "3")
        .validateText(props.get("select"), "3")

        // frames
        .switchToFrame("frame") // the id="frame"
        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("div#frame_content"))

        // windows
        .switchToWindow("Getting Started with Selenium") // switch back to the test window.
        .click(By.linkText("Open a new tab / window"))
        .waitForWindow("Google") // waits for the url.  Can also be the you are expecting. :) (regex enabled too)
        .setText(By.name("q"), "google!")
        .closeWindow(); // we've closed google, and back on the getting started with selenium page.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of a WebDriver and call methods on the instance of that object.

An easy example is shown here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created the script in webdriver.

Now in the script recorded by the selenium ide you have three methods called 
**setup, testSomeName and tearDown**.

From the very basic: to run this script all you need to do is create a main method in the same class and in that you need to call these methods in the same order as specified above.

After that you just need to run that program.

Here is an example to make it more clear:

```
public class p_adjcb {

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    public void testP_adjcb() throws Exception {
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        p_adjcb obj = new p_adjcb();
        try {
            obj.setUp();
            obj.testP_adjcb();
            obj.tearDown();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

If you get any compiler error make sure you have downloaded the `selenium-standalone-server.jar` file and added it to your class path.
This is a very basic start. Later on you may need to use som framework like **junit**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is bad.. why would you put junit tests in there if you aren't even using junit .. you are handling this task with Java, not jUnit like you should.

Comment: @sircapsalot: Thanks a lot. Just removed the annotations.

Comment: ah yes, much better :)